# php validate a pattern with regex

Tags: php, regex

I try to validate a pattern like `123*5000`.
The pattern has 3 parts.

First, the [123] must contain three digits unique number.
The second is `*`, and the third is 5000, must be an integer, not unique is fine.

If the pattern is `223*443` it will return false (first part 223, number 2 it not unique).

If the pattern is `908*22` it will return true (first part contain unique number, second part is `*`, third part is integer).

If the pattern is `34*5000` it will return false (first part only contain 2 digits), and etc.

I try regex `\^[0-9][0-9][0-9][*][0-9]+$\` but it did not solve the first part pattern that must contains unique number.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)\d{3}\*\d+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\d*(\d)\d*\1)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 of the same digits
- `\d{3}\*\d+` Match 3 digits, then `*` and 1 or more digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFelxa/1).